# UIActivityIndicatorView displayed beneath the keyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertview, uiactivityindicatorview

Inside a static library (lib.a), I have a `NavigationController` in a Storyboard that I initiate after a button tap with:

```
[mainWindow.rootViewController presentViewController:newController animated:NO completion:Nil];
```

Within that `newController` I have a `UITextField` that I set `becomeFirstResponder` upon `viewDidLoad` and another button that when tapped I want to display a `UIAlertView` which after pressing "Ok" should show a `UIActivityIndicatorView` on top of everything (including the keyboard).

The code am using to display the `UIActivityIndicatorView` is the following

```
UIWindow *mainWindow = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhite];
spinner.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin |
                            UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin |
                            UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin |
                            UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin);
spinner.center = CGPointMake(CGRectGetWidth(mainWindow.bounds)/2, CGRectGetHeight(mainWindow.bounds)/2);
spinner.frame = mainWindow.bounds;
spinner.backgroundColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
spinner.alpha = 0.7f;
[mainWindow addSubview:spinner];
```

and whenever the user taps on the button I execute the following:

```
UIAlertView *message = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Confirmation"
                                                      message:@"Are you sure?"
                                                     delegate:self
                                            cancelButtonTitle:@"No"
                                            otherButtonTitles:@"Yes", nil];
[message show];
```

and when tapped I have a simple method that:

```
//Initializing spinner
[spinner startAnimating];

 //Execute NSURL Connection....
```

The problem is that the `UIActivityIndicatorView` does not show on top of the keyboard.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

try to add after

```
[mainWindow addSubview:spinner];
```

something like

```
[mainWindow bringSubviewToFront:spinner];
```

Try to use this view as superview for UIActivityIndicatorView

```
- (UIView *)keyboardView {
    NSArray *windows = [[UIApplicatio sharedApplication] windows];
    for (UIWindow *window in [windows reverseObjectEnumerator]) {
        for (UIView *view in [window subviews]) {
            if (!strcmp(object_getClassName(view), "UIKeyboard"))  {
                return view;
            }
        }
    }

    return nil;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I've tried that already but still shows beneath the keyboard.

Comment: I've tried the edited comment but it still shows underneath the keyboard. I've edited my description considering I forgot to mention all of this is done inside a static library.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `UIActivityIndicatorView` to be the frontest subView of the window before you show the indicator

add the code : `[mainWindow bringSubviewToFront:spinner];` before `[spinner startAnimating];`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I've tried this and still shows beneath the keyboard :(